# Antlr Parser acting weird

Tags: antlr4

I have this weird behavior of the parser for my anltr configuration.
This was working as intended so far but now we found some additional cases when antlr crushes.

this is the lexer:

```
lexer grammar RuleLexer;


WORD: (DIGIT | LOWERCASE | UPPERCASE)+;
ANY_SPACE: (SINGLE_SPACE | NEW_LINE)+;

WS: [\r\t]+ -> skip;

CONDITION_OPEN: '<';
CONDITION_CLOSE: '>';
AND: '&';
OR: '/';

fragment LOWERCASE: [a-z];
fragment UPPERCASE: [A-Z];
fragment DIGIT: [0-9];
fragment SINGLE_SPACE: ' ';
fragment NEW_LINE: [\n];
```

and here is the parser:

```
parser grammar RuleParser;

options {
    tokenVocab = RuleLexer;
    language = Java;
}

rules: term+ EOF;

term:
    constraint EOF                                                      # statement
    | fi = constraint CONDITION_OPEN then = constraint CONDITION_CLOSE  # conditional;

constraint:
    ANY_SPACE? (element) ANY_SPACE? (
        operation constraint
    )?;

operation: AND | OR;

element: WORD;
```

Here are some imputs and picrures with the results:
001/002/003 -> works fine:
[001/002/003](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxwZj.png)

But now the weird part comes in. If i add another operator / or & at the end of the input
001/002/003/ -> doesn't work.
[001/002/003/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jG74U.png)

If i have a conditional as input the parser works as desired. It validates the input and identifies the extra operation:
001<002/003>/ -> is working
[001<002/003>/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pratG.png)
I would like second input to be interpreted  like the third.

And the last issue i discovered is when i'm missing an operation between constraints.
001/002 003/004
[001/002 003/004](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVBd5.png)

I am wondering why I have this results with EOF and null in the cases when is not working.
I hope the picture resolution is good enough.

Comment: `001<002/003>/` is not parsed correctly. The screenshot shows the error that is emitted: `extraneous input '/' expecting {<EOF>, WORD, ANY_SPACE}`. There's also a red node in the parse tree to indicate that the parse didn't succeed.

Comment: I know! But that helps me to find the error there which is the extra operator. Because I also have to identify the error if there is one. In this example the rest of the tree is fine.
But in the example 001/002/003/ the output is totally different and the tree is messed up.
What I’m looking for in the end is to send a message to the one who is filling the input like this in this case: you are missing an element. 
Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

With the `constraint EOF # statement` alternative, you're only matching a constraint *IF* it's the only thing in the entire input stream.

You're treating Spaces and newLines equivalently, so, is your intention to allow multiple constraint terms in an input stream?  If so, you need to drop the `EOF` on that rule alternative.

Since you've defined `/` as the OR operator that is only available if followed by another constraint, it's not valid at the end of the input. So, you get the `no viable alternative` error message.  It appears that you'd *prefer* to get the `extraneous input '/' expecting ...` error instead.

You get that message with the `EOF` on the `statement` alternative (for *some* input), because ANTLR is able to use some of it's error recovery strategies. The `extraneous input` error is something ANTLR attempts to do for more graceful error recovery (sort of a "hmmmm... I can make sense of that *if* I ignore this token).  However, ANTLR  isn't always able to attempt these error recoveries.  (I *thought* I had a handle on when they would fire and when they would not, but could not modify this grammar to take advantage of how I *thought* it worked.  I'm sure it's rather complex internals that are involved in whether certain error recovery strategies are applicable.

With this modification to the term rule:

```
term:
    fi = constraint (
        CONDITION_OPEN then = constraint CONDITION_CLOSE
    )?;
```

I get `line 1:12 mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting {WORD, ANY_SPACE}` instead of the `no viable alternative` error message.  This does seem to be a more specific error message.

That said, this appears to be a rather stripped-down grammar, and this change to avoid alternatives may not be practical in the larger scope.

In the end, `no viable alternative` error messages are quite likely to occur.

You could also look into implementing you're own Error Recovery Strategy, but that's more often used to skip certain strategies to avoid the overhead.  Adding more logic is likely an "expert" level endeavor.

NOTE:  One rather clever alternative I just noticed in the ANTLR book is that if you have certain common errors (like, say a trailing '/') you can add a rule to detect the error specifically.

```
constraint:
    ANY_SPACE? (element) ANY_SPACE? (operation constraint)?
    | ANY_SPACE? (element) ANY_SPACE? operation {notifyErrorListeners("operation without following constraint");
        };
```

gives: `line 1:12 operation without following constraint` for input `001/002/003/`

Comment: BTW... unless you have other plans for the future, your ANY_SPACE token isn't really doing anything valuable, and you'd clean up your parse rules by either "-> skip"ing them or sending them to the HIDDEN channel.